# WooCommerce пересчёт количества результатов до фильтрации

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Разрабатываю сайт с WooCommerce, поставили несколько задач, не могу найти решения.
Заказчик хочет, чтобы количество найденных товаров рассчитывалось и отображалось до нажатия кнопки "фильтровать". Сейчас использую WOO filters, пока только он подошёл, чтобы результаты поиска обновлялись не сразу при выборе характеристики, а после того, как выбрано несколько.
Вот как должно выглядеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После выбора значения обновляется количество товаров. Примерно как на яндекс маркете. С ajax не дружу :( Помогите

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, WooCommerce Products Filter нигде не в своём коде не подсчитывает количество товаров до фильтрации.

Вам надо вешать JQuery обработчик .change() на инпуты характеристик товара, в нём делать вызов ajax, в php-коде делать выборку по базе с подсчётом числа товаров, возвращать это число в js, и выводить на странице в поле "Найдено товаров:".

Если нет навыков в ajax и php, чтобы сделать выборку по базе, лучше поручить эту задачу фрилансеру.